# Equivalent of C# Enum Flags Attribute in Java?

Tags: java

RE C# enums with the flag attribute:

http://dotnetperls.com/enum-flags

is there any way to get this behavior in Java?

Comment: man, c# has no fear of enlarging the language. in any case enum and set of enums sharing the same type sounds very wrong.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As long as you define your Enum values properly, you can use [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to get that functionality.

```
RenderSet set = RenderSet.DataUri | RenderSet.GZip;
```

would become

```
EnumSet.of(RenderSet.DataUri, RenderSet.GZip);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "define your Enum values properly"

Answer (score -9):

Yes. Java Version 1.5 onwards has a support for enums. Refer http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html for usage.

Comment: This is unhelpful to the question asked, which is about storing groups of enums in a bitmask like structure.